# How to use WrapGrid Orientation?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, gridview

I am fairly new to XAML / WPF programming. I would like to ask how to do a particular line of code from XAML into C#?

XAML:

```
<GridView>
  <ItemsPanelTemplate>
    <WrapGrid Orientation="Horizontal"/>
  </ItemsPanelTemplate>
</GridView>
```

How can I do this in C#?

Comment: are you looking for tree genration in code or just to edit the wrapGrid editing. if tree genration then google for FrameworkElementFactory class

Answer (score 3):

If you give the control a name, like this:

```
<GridView>
  <ItemsPanelTemplate>
    <WrapGrid Name="MyWrapGrid" Orientation="Horizontal"/>
  </ItemsPanelTemplate>
</GridView>
```

You can do this in code behind (C#) to change the orientation:

```
MyWrapGrid.Orientation = Orientation.Horizontal;
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the answer! Can you elaborate more on how I can assign the wrapgrid orientation to the ItemsPanelTemplate of the GridView? Thank you!